# Bring HTC Wildfire back to the original rom

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, htc-wildfire, unrooting

I am an HTC Wildfire user. I have successfully installed CyanogenMod 7.2 on my device, but after over a year of use I want to bring it back to the original HTC rom, if possibile. In order to do that I have tried to follow a few tutorials that promised to do just that. Needless to say they all failed.

My HTC has mounted HBoot 0.80.007 and it is in S-On state and, maybe I am wrong, but I figured I should update the HBoot to 1.01.001 at least and in order to do that I need to acquire the S-Off. So I tried to download the Revolutionary utility but I had no luck in providing my Wildfire serial number.

As a result I am clueless about what to do. Can anyone please illustrate what I need to do to bring my device back to the original rom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my attempts to I was trying to upgrade the hboot from 0.80.0007 to 1.01 and luckily flashing the device with [RUU_Buzz_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.22.405.1_Radio_13.55.55.24H_3.35.20.10_release_160191_signed.exe](http://www.shipped-roms.com/download.php?category=android&model=Buzz&file=RUU_Buzz_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.22.405.1_Radio_13.55.55.24H_3.35.20.10_release_160191_signed.exe) it also brought my Wildfire to the stock rom.